# Would sentient aliens be legal persons?

Tags: united-states

Suppose some sentient aliens figure out how to receive our radio and TV broadcasts. They eventually decode the English language, and a few of them study it enough to be fluent. They land somewhere in the United States, perfectly capable of conversing with humans. Are they legal persons?

Since they obviously aren't citizens, are they illegal "aliens" (in the legal sense of the word "alien")?

If a person stole from one of the aliens, could the alien sue?

Comment: I can see this applying to whether or not a search is lawful. If a UFO landed, presumably at least one government agency would want to investigate, but could they enter the UFO legally?

Comment: The better question is: The UFO lands. Can Police just gun the aliens down because the Aliens are not protected as "people" from state action depriving them of life?! Does it change with them being ["starfish aliens"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StarfishAliens) instead of humanoid ["green skinned space babes"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GreenSkinnedSpaceBabe)?

Comment: Depends on how big their gun are. Since they can travel between stars and we cannot, I will tend to assume than theirs are bigger.

Comment: We'll find out when we get there. Not all legal questions have non-speculative answers in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite possibly such hypothetical non-human intelligent beings would be treated as legal persons, but one cannot be sure in advance. If when humans first encountered such beings, they routinely treated them as persons, that might well influence any later legal treatment. If, on the other hand, humans initial treated such beings as "dumb animals".

Eventually, there would no doubt have to be new law passed, or a court ruling on how existing law was to be applied to such beings, rt quite possibly both. One would**hope** that the law would treat such beings as fully human, but such past cases as [*Dred Scott v. Sandford*, 60 U.S. (19 How.) 393 (1857)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dred_Scott_v._Sandford) make tyhst less assuted than one might wish.

Comment: If it was ruled that they were legal persons, would they then be illegal aliens? Could they be deported?

Comment: (not sure where an alien would be deported to)

Comment: @Someone Off-earth of course.

Comment: @Trish where off earth? A human illegal alien is deported to the country they came from, not just any country outside the US, right?

Comment: @Someone they had means to get to the US, their starship is supposedly capable of getting them home. That is, if they keep it and it is not confiscated, gutted and the aliens turned into a taxidermy practice for Xenobiologists.

Comment: Could *Dred Scott v. Sandford* actually be precedent? AFAIK it was never actually overturned; the 13th amendment just made black people citizens if they meet the other requirements.

Comment: @Someone I believe the judicial and legal consensus is that *Dread Scott* ia no longer good law, in any sense. The Wikipedia article on the case reads: "*Charles Evans Hughes, writing in 1927 on the Supreme Court's history, described Dred Scott v. Sandford as a 'self-inflicted wound' from which the court would not recover for many years*" All post-civil-war cites of *Dread Scott* seem to portray it as a horrible example, not a precedent.

Comment: @DavidSiegel so it hasn't technically been overturned, but it probably would be overturned if a case where it could possibly be precedent came up?

Comment: @Someone I have herd a lawyer say that even to cite *Dred Scott* favorably at an oral argument is to risk losing the case.  It has had a drastically negative effect on Chief Justice Taney's  historical reputation  Another case is the Sedition act of 1797. It was repealed before it was ever passed on by the Supreme Court, but Justices have mentioned that if it came up it would clearly be found unconstitutional now.

Comment: @Someone: *Dred Scott* does not need to be overruled by the Court (whether or not it was bad law when it was decided in 1857) because the opinion's central holding on Black citizenship was deliberately and directly addressed, and reversed or superseded, by the birthright citizenship clause of the 14th Amendment (1868): "Section 1. All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and of the State wherein they reside."

Comment: The case didn't have anything to do with whether or not Black Americans were "fully human" or whether they counted legally as "persons"; this is taken for granted in Taney's opinion and Black people are repeatedly referred to as "persons," part of "the whole human family," etc. The question is whether or not such persons, admitted to be such, could be or become *citizens of the United States* & of their states of residence. Taney held -- wrongly, and outrageously, -- that they couldn't. (Hence the Constitutional Amendment to settle the question and take it out of the hands of Court precedent.)

Answer (score 1):

**Precedent would have to be set, probably with governments in the lead.**

It would be possible legislatures make decisions to force the government's hand, or that courts intervene (on behalf of the extraterrestrials). But in all likelihood, governments would make the first decisions in the name of *national security.*

So this is not really a suitable question for Law SE. You might pose the question in Worldbuilding SE, but that is distinctly *fictional*.

When it comes to law, consider the [precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_ape_personhood) of primates. Primates are not *homo sapiens sapiens*, not even *homo*, only *hominoidae*. Their rights in the United States are weaker than in Europe, and not even Europe gives them rights like a human.

The extraterrestrials' status as "illegal aliens" would depend on how they come in. If they had government permission to land, without conditions communicated beforehand, they could later argue in court that they were recognized as legal persons and given entry permission. Revoking that would raise the question if they can leave. But the government might argue that they are not allowed their time in court, with a variety of good and bad explanations ...

Comment: Amazingly, there actually is a precedent.  A court has decided that Martians are not legal persons.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joly_v_Pelletier

Comment: That was in Canada, but the same argument would apply in USA.

Comment: Checked your link which says among other things that corporations have rights. Could aliens form a corporation? I have a limited company in the UK and I don’t think anyone asked me if I was human. They asked for my name, date of birth, address and that’s all things an alien could have. I’m sure an alien with a small bag of diamonds would manage to get legal citizenship and a legal passport in _some_ country. With a big bag of diamonds they could surely get all the necessary law changes. And then he/she/it/they have to decide on their pronouns :-)

Comment: @gnasher729, those changes in the law would surely be in the realm of Worldbuilding SE, unless you are thinking of actual extraterrestrials in a legal quagmire.